# Get a simple string from an API

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit

I would like to get a simple string from an API.
Usually, i can get everything I want from an API with the following functions :

```
class OrderRepositoryImpl(val orderService: OrderService) : OrderRepository {
        override fun getPaymentMethods(id: String, success: (List<PaymentMode>) -> Unit, failure: (Throwable) -> Unit): Subscription {
            return orderService.getPaymentMethods(id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { it.entrySet() }
                .map { it.map { it.value }.map {it.asJsonObject } }
                .map { it.map { PaymentMode().apply { loadFromJson(it) } } }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ success.invoke(it) }, { failure.invoke(it) })
        }
}
```

And in OrderService :

```
@GET("api/order/payment/modes/list/{id}")
fun getPaymentMethods(@Path("id") id: String): Observable<JsonObject>
```

This works perfectly, on an API with regular Json Objects.

But today, I have a problem : I have an API with a unique string, like this :

```
"validated"
```

or :

```
"draft"
```

So I made the followin function (in OrderRepositoryImpl class) :

```
override fun getOrderStatus(id: String, success: (String) -> Unit, failure: (Throwable) -> Unit) =
    orderService.getOrderStatus(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { it }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ success.invoke(it.toString()) }, { failure.invoke(it) } )
```

And in Order Service :

```
@GET("api/order/checkout/{id}/status")
fun getOrderStatus(@Path("id") id: String): Observable<JsonObject>
```

I call this method like this :

```
fun getOrderStatus(id : Long) {
    orderRepository.getOrderStatus(id.toString(), {
        println("SUCCESS !")
        println("STATUS == $it")
    }, {
        println("FAILURE...")
    })
}
```

But I don't get anything from "success.invoke" line. When I call this method in my code, i always have "FAILURE" in my logs... Even if one of the logs lines is :

```
D/OkHttp: "validated"
```

which is exactly what I want to see in case of success.

I know it is pretty strange I can get and parse json objects and not a string, but I kind of learned on the job...
How can I get a simple string from an API ?

Comment: print out the throwable that causes this and voila

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am SO ashamed.

So, I printed the error in my "FAILURE..." section, and I got something like :

```
got jsonPrimitive but expected jsonObject
```

As the API was just returning me a string, and NOT an object, it is call a Json Primitive.
So I just changed the return of my functions in OrderService :

```
@GET("api/order/checkout/{id}/status")
fun getOrderStatus(@Path("id") id: String): Observable<JsonPrimitive>
```

Thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ServiceInterFace {
@POST("api/order/checkout/{id}/status")
fun getOrderStatus(@Path("id") id: String): Call<String>
} 

// calling from your main class

val id: String? = null
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl("----Your link here-----")
    .build()

val scalarService = retrofit.create(ServiceInterFace::class.java!!)
val stringCall = scalarService.getOrderStatus(id)
stringCall.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val responseString = response.body()//get response here     
    }
}

override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
    Toast.makeText(this@Main2Activity, "Failed to connect server",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
})

//import 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'    
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
```